# Azure Mobile Services - table.read().done(function (results)) returning undefined values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, azure-mobile-services

EDIT: The function is asynchronous so console.log was fired before the data was returned. I'll be putting my logic inside this `.done()` function now.

I'm trying to take the results array and pass it into a global variable but the variable is logging as undefined outside of the results function.

It is however the array I need INSIDE the function.

I need to have an array of objects OUTSIDE of the results function as I cannot debug inside this function and have alot of code to write

Here is the code

```js
$scope.syncContacts = function () {

        var table = AzureService.getTable('contact');
        var contactList = [];
        table.read().done(function (results) {
            contactList = results;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                console.log("Contact Object:", results[i]);
            }
            console.log('contact list is : ', contactList);
        });
        console.log("OUTSIDE FUNCTION LIST", contactList);
    };
```

I have been reading around and have seen a function `response.send(200, results)` being used in azure tables but have no idea what its used for or if I need it.

Comment: contactList has two definitions in two different scopes. The one that you are printing is the top one, that is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a variable scope issue wth `contactList`, you are print the outside variable, and creating a new one inside the promise to populate.

```
var table = AzureService.getTable('contact');
table.read().done(function (results) {
   $scope.contactList = results;
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
     console.log("Contact Object:", results[i]);
   }
   console.log('contact list is : ',$scope.contactList);
});
```

Here's the oficial documentation for AzureService JavaScript: [Add Mobile Services to an existing app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-javascript-get-started-data/)

**EDIT:**

The `contactList` is being printed undefined because of the promise resolution. The `done` method will take some time to get the data from the server. But, if you print it inside the `done`, It will show up the result, as expected. You should put this value inside a `$scope` variable, then you can use It after the read returns the data from the server:

Comment: I have updated the code to what you posted and contactlist is not being populated by the results. Just stays as an empty array

Comment: @GaryMcNeill You should try the way I showed. You must assign the value inside the done method, not the way you are trying.

Comment: I have tried the code you posted but it is not working. I need to have a variable with the results information OUTSIDE the `function(results)` function as I cannot debug inside this function

Comment: @GaryMcNeill checkout the Edit

Comment: That only gives me the array inside of the `table.read` I need it to be passed to a global variable. 

I appreciate your help by the way

Comment: @GaryMcNeill You are wrong, if you put it inside the $scope variable, It will be avaible anywhere you have the controlle that has this $scope. If you need to share It between controllers, you should consider to create a Service to hold this contactList

Comment: @GaryMcNeill no way, you have to assign the result value to any variable from inside the promise, in this case, inside the done method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83252/discussion-between-gary-mcneill-and-fals).